# Flex 3.5 multiline htmlText scrolls 1-2 lines

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, htmltext

It's easy to reproduce. If you are using Flex 3.5 (not my choice) and you scroll the mousewheel over a Text component with multiple lines of htmlText, it will scroll down 1 (sometimes 2) lines, even though there is no text there.

Any ideas how to adjust this? Even if I had to extend Text and modify it, I want to fix this issue.

Thanks!

Before: http://cl.ly/18373k441T0p080n2w0M

After: http://cl.ly/0g2T1v161t2l2c3T0k0S

Please note, I made sure there is not a blank line below the body of text (it ended after the closing). Notice how the top line is now cut off, and an extra line was added at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions for that. Please read [this](http://viconflex.blogspot.com/2008/08/mxcontrolstext-preventing-scroll-on.html) and [this](http://flexceptional.blogspot.com/2011/03/flex-disable-mouse-wheel-scrolling-for.html). As for me the first one is more preferable. You can extend standard component with this solution.

Comment: I love it. The first solution is totally a hack but it does what I want it to do. I am fairly certain the TLF in Flex 4 doesn't have this issue, why don't all of our users have flash player 10 :(

Answer (score 0):

Set `mouseEnabled = false;` if you do not require any mouse interaction.

Comment: removed `mouseWheelEnabled`, thought it was text field, sry for that.